# How did Quim's death save Lusitania from a holocaust?

Tags: xenocide

In *Children of the Mind*, Novinha and Ender are having a conversation about Quim's death in *Xenocide*:

> Novinha: I even know that now.  It's right.  It was right for [Quim] to go, and it was even right for him to die, because his death meant something. Didn't it?
>
> Ender: It saved Lusitania from a holocaust.

How did Quim's death save Lusitania from a holocaust?  In *Xenocide*, Quim's death directly led to the human population murdering almost the entirety of the neighboring Pequinino village, which sounds like the opposite.  Did Ender mean that those events led to Grego's incarceration which indirectly allowed him to develop theories about the Inside/Outside, which then allowed FTL travel and the creation of the recolada?  Or did Ender mean something else?  What would have happened differently if Quim had stayed?

Comment:  Somebody used [the word "quim"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/quim) as a name?

Comment: @JRE https://enderverse.fandom.com/wiki/Quim_Ribeira#Trivia

Comment: @JRE Quim [is short for Joaquim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quim) in Portuguese, and the character who bore the name in the book came from a society heavily influenced by Portuguese culture. I doubt the American author was familiar with the UK slang term. Especially since I don't believe it is particularly common even in the UK (at least, I've been living in the UK for around a decade now and had never heard of it before reading your comment).

Comment: @terdon:  It is common enough that I, as an American, have heard of it

Comment: That's certainly how one would approximate "king" with Portuguese phonology, but I do not know why someone would do it in this context. If a Portguese speaker, one would just stick with rei; if one also spoke English, one would surely use "king."

Comment: @terdon author tags are for questions about the author, not for questions about their works

Comment: Ah, sorry @fez, I didn't know that. Thanks for the info!

Comment: @JRE huh. I, as an american (albeit one not raised in the US, but still one raised as a native speaker) had not. And I can only find it in British dictionaries and have never heard it used in the UK. All of which is purely anecdotal, of course. However, given that the author is a devout Mormon, I really doubt he'd use a vulgar slang term knowingly. Kinda wish he had, to be honest :)

Comment: @Adamant The bilingual nature of the colonists came up often in the novels, with the pequininos even adopting the tendency of the colonists to use English commonly but Portuguese for emphasis. Their names were distinctly Portuguese, though, so I guess the author figured that even if everyone was saying 'king' since it's a name it should be spelled like a Portuguese word. Just a guess, though.

Comment: @JRE et all: That's nothing compared to the original name for the "formics"; particularly distracting when you find out that he's an outspoken opponent of homosexuality. I _think_ that one was just a coincidence as well, but ... eugh.

Answer (score 1):

While he would consider the violence immediately after to be tragic, Ender has the the specific and unique perspective of wiping out an entire sapient species with a single act, which is definitely what he means by the word 'holocaust'. He is definitely recognizing Quim's death as the inciting incident that led to saving the planet from the MD device.

> Did Ender mean that those events led to Grego's incarceration which indirectly allowed him to develop theories about the Inside/Outside, which then allowed FTL travel and the creation of the recolada?

I believe you already found the right answer. Specifically, all of Novinha's kids were brilliant but independent, and Quim's death unified them in a way necessary to make all of the discoveries they did.

Although, it's likely that Ender and Novinha are looking back and attempting to find a greater purpose behind his death, a rationalization to make his absence easier to accept even after all that time. While that event may have been the little domino that pushed them along the path they followed, it's impossible to say that it's the only cause that could get them to the same end. Novinha needed comforting in that moment, and that explanation helped her.

Comment: Could you elaborate on *how* Quim's death led to saving the planet?  Grego's incarceration?  Something else?  What would have happened differently if Quim had not died?

Comment: Why though, do you remember? I was trying to remember the link but I couldn't. I do recall it seemed like a natural connection last time I read the books, but I don't remember what the causal link between Quim's death and the decision not to use the MD device was.

Comment: The MD device was launched. The captain of that ship was certain that his name would go down in infamy alongside Ender's. Jane used the FTL box to get the MD missile and I think even put it back on the ship that launched it.

Comment: So the causality link is Quim's death lead to the FTL box breakthrough and that, in turn, was used to save the planet?